# Nested vs. Large Arrays Performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm working on a game and was trying to decide on a schema for my tile maps, however as they could potentially be fairly large, I was curious as to the difference in performance between the two approaches I see. For each frame, I would need to run through every cell in each array, so the number of items is the same, however does nesting the Arrays impact performance in any way?

---

Option 1: Nested Arrays

```
[[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3],[c1,c2,c3]]
```

This would be a lot more readable, but could potentially impact performance (due to larger number of arrays?)?

---

Option 2: Single Large Array

```
[a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3]
```

This would be more complicated to implement, however would it yield and performance gain?
Thanks in advance!

---

Edit 1:
The idea behind the arrays is each element would be a custom object, containing properties of a tile in a JRPG style game. A `for` loop would iterate over each array and retrieve data from each object to draw a tile in a `<canvas>` element as the player moves about the world.

Comment: really, the best thing to do is try both and see what is more performant in your case, but that's just *opinion*

Comment: @JaromandaX: No, "the best way to find the best way is to benchmark" is not an opinion, but a fact (with a proviso "if benchmarking doesn't cost you too much") - :) The accompanying opinion is "nested arrays are a bit slower but the lost time should be in nanoseconds and thus completely ignorable" :P

Comment: You can only judge performance based on comparison of different methods that achieve the same result. If all you are doing is storing the data, what performance difference do you expect? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @RobG essentially, each item would be a custom object which would render a tile in a canvas

Comment: Where "render a tile" is left to the imagination…

Comment: @Amadan - *try both* is fact, it being the *best thing* to do is opinion :p